# Sudden problem with Bluetooth: No Bluetooth found and Plug a dongle to use Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

I have a problem with Bluetooth on my PC; I put Ubuntu on my Laptop. I have never had a problem but recently, the Bluetooth no longer works. It has always worked very well but overnight the Bluetooth no longer works — it shows me "No Bluetooth Found" "Plug a dongle to use Bluetooth". I don't know what to do. I have recently formatted my PC and completely reinstalled Linux. I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

this is the results for `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:671e Microdia Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 27c6:538d Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. FingerPrint
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c53f Logitech, Inc. USB Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And for `lspci` :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Plus Graphics G7 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 8a03 (rev 03)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP DRAM Controller (rev 30)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 30)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Management Engine (rev 30)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 30)
00:19.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2c Controller #4 (rev 30)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev 30)
00:1d.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 34b1 (rev 30)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 34b4 (rev 30)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP LPC Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SMBus Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SPI Controller (rev 30)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: KIOXIA Corporation Device 0001
```

Comment: oh yeah my bad i'm french

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu. Please provide the type of Bluetooth and/or make and model you are using. If you are using a USB Bluetooth, you can find information using the `lsusb` command. Most importantly here, is the alphanumeric code for the USB device which is something like abcd:1234 or something similar like a1b2:c3d4. If not a USB device, then use the `lspci` command to list all your devices and then look for the Bluetooth device in the results. Also, please provide the version of Ubuntu. Thanks.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and I've no idea witch device is but it's not an usb device,and `lspci `returns me a lots of things

Comment: I have not 'bluetooth controler', it's probably this ? :`02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
`

Comment: Those wifi had included Bluetooth that show up in results from terminal for `lsusb` please edit the question to include those results